# How to affect outer loop variable from inner loop in Python?

Tags: java, python, for-loop, conditional-statements

This is in Java:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
    while(i%3!=0)
        i++;
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

This will output:

> 0 3 6 9

I am trying to achieve similar code block in Python 3. I am not able to.

In the outer loop, I can not use range because it causes iteration on whole list I read somewhere I think. So, I am trying below, but it fails dangerously, running infinitely.

```
i=1
while i<=10:
    while i%3 is not 0:
        i+=1
    print('run')
```

I could have achieved target by removing internal `while` and changing the code to `i+=3`. But the program I am trying to make has important conditions so it has to be there. **There has to be two loops and based on inner loop condition matching, I am incrementing the iteration variable, so when I break and process some program output, then the parent loop should start iterating from where I left off in inner loop.** Above is just an example I could think of to share the issue. I need suggestion on how can I replicate the changes as described in Java code in Python.

**Update:** Here is program for which I was trying this: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/327908/finding-total-number-of-subarrays-from-given-array-of-numbers-with-equal-max-and

Comment: Well, you don't increment i once it hits 3, so of course it runs infinitely.

Comment: Your outer for-loop is never incrementing i. So, if i starts at 0, it will forever remain 0 due to the lack of an increment.

Also, if you're wanting to print out every third number from [0, 10] on a single line, why not just do something like:

`for i in range(0, 11, 3): print(i, end=' ')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    while i % 3 is not 0:
        i += 1
    print(str(i) + " ")
    i += 1
```

Comment: @xploreraj Then the top answer I gave is what you want.

Comment: This seems like an exact match of the java version, isn't it?

Comment: @Aguy It is. You basically can't get any closer than this in Python.

Comment: Dont know where mind was when I missed outer increment, without that as @Dallan pointed, it gets stuck forever. Probably hung late night!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for two loops in your example.

```
while i<=10:
  if i%3 == 0:
    print(i+ " ")
  i++
```

Your code runs infinitely because you never increment i when it equals 3

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to just use a list comprehension:

```
print(' '.join([i for i in range(10) if i % 3 == 0])
```

Comment: Just increment outside of the inner loop.

The outer loop is running forever because there's nothing changing the value of i once the inner loop completes. If, however, your desired output is the 0 3 6 9 example you gave, go with @Dallan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Another suggestion for the party. Might be helpful with your actual task:

```
g = iter(range(10))
for i in g:
    while i%3 is not 0:
        i = next(g)
    print(i)
```

The main difference is that this will raise `StopIteration` exception when the inner loop exceeds the range defined for the iterator (i.e. for the outer loop). Might be something desired, or might not.

Comment: Interesting. Introduces to me the iter function.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment on the OP's question:

`for i in range(0, 11, 3): print(i, end=' ')`